Nginx + Django Static Files issue
I am having an issue with my project. I have everything working in my Django project, when the DEBUG=True in settings.py. But as soon as I change it to False, I get this issue when I go to my website (localhost):
Error message with localhost when DEBUG=False
Which probably means that either my static files are not correctly sent to my Nginx, or my Nginx web server is not correctly configured to receive/use my static files.
Here is the docker-compose I am using:
version: '3.8'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:13
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres

  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@db:5432/postgres

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    depends_on:
      - web
    restart: on-failure  # Ensures NGINX retries if it fails to start the first time

  migrations:
    build: .
    command: sh -c "python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate"
    depends_on:
      - db


volumes:
  postgres_data:

Dockerfile for my Django project:
# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:3.9-slim

# Set environment varibles
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Set work directory
WORKDIR /app

# Install dependencies
COPY requirements.txt /app/
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install -r requirements.txt

# Copy project
COPY . /app/

settings.py STATIC_FILES:
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / 'webapp' / 'static',
]

Nginx Dockerfile:
# Use the official NGINX image from Docker Hub
FROM nginx:1.21.6

# Remove the default nginx.conf
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

# Copy the custom nginx.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/

# Copy your SSL certificate and key
COPY certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt /etc/nginx/certs/
COPY certs/nginx-selfsigned.key /etc/nginx/certs/

Nginx.conf:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;  # Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name localhost;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/nginx-selfsigned.key;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://web:8000;  # Note: http not https
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}

I have been stuck on this for 3 days, if any of you has any ideas please help, thanks a lot !
I have already tried a lot of different ways to redo all of my Dockerfiles and .conf of my project, without any success unfortunately.

Don't forget to collect static when Debug = False. It is most likely that you get 404 HTML page when you ask for JS or CSS files, hence the error. You also needs to serve static files by any other mean than django, so you have to update your NGinx config as well to serve those collected static files.

When DEBUG=False, Django does not serve static files as it does when DEBUG=True so you have to take it in charge.
You are most likely having 404 HTML response hence your errors.
First collect static files:
python manage.py collectstatic

To ask django to collect all static files and put them in a single folder that will be used by NGinx to serve them.
Then update your NGinx configuration in order to serve those files:
server {
    listen 80;
    ...
    location /static/ {
        root /path/to/static;
    }
    ...
}

